# Changing the notification icon in angular component

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a notification plugin integrated in angular

Currently it shows different icons for error ,success ,warning so on...

How can i change that icon?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example

Comment: Are you on angular or angularjs? Please update tags accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply configure the settings for `angular2-notifications`.

Sample code:

```
// In NgModule, where you're importing the module.
SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot( {
      icons: {
        success: '<i class="icon-check-sign icon-3x"></i>',
        alert: '<i class="icon-exclamation icon-3x"></i>',
        error: '<i class="icon-bug icon-3x"></i>',
        info: '<i class="icon-info icon-3x"></i>',
        warn: '<i class="icon-warning-sign icon-3x"></i>'
      }
 })
```

*Note: In this example, I'm using icon of FontAwesome 3.2.1*

I've the changes the icons in [stackblitz code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-font-awesome-example?file=app/app.module.ts)

[Check out their docs for full info](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications).

Comment: just curious how i can show the icon on left side, rather than right side

Comment: This should be a fresh question. Anyway, you just need to change the `rtl` property when you're configuring into AppModule. & you need change little bit of css. here is the stackblitz snippet https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-notifications-example-font-awesome-example-icon-left?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts